# Java Servlets - reaching SUCCESS in ajax

Tags: java, ajax

I have a problem with interaction between my jsp and servlet using ajax. I want servlet to send error to jsp if the user already exists (it shouldn't save the user), and redirect to another page (if the user doesn't exist and servlet saves it).

```
$.ajax({
                        type : "POST",
                        url:"/adminUser?save=save",
                        dataType:'json',
                        data: {save: 'save', login:login, pass1:pass1, userName:userName, email:email,
                            bukhUsersId: bukhUsersId, otdelId: otdelId, roleId: roleId, checkActive: checkActive},
                        success: function () {
                            top.location.href = "/adminUser?action=spisok";
                        } ,
                        error : function(xhr, status, error) {
                            $("#errorLogin").text("Пользователь с таким логином уже существует");
                        }
                    });
```

Here's a fragment of my servlet:

```
            String login = request.getParameter("login");
            if (adminSecurityDAOImpl.isUserExist(login)) {
                response.sendError(400, "Пользователь с таким логином уже существует");
                response.flushBuffer();
                return;
            }
            else {
                adminSecurityDAOImpl.saveUser(user);

                //response.getWriter().write("SUCCESS");
                response.flushBuffer();
               `return
            }
        }
```

I don't understand how to reach that success part. I tried sending back 200 status code, returning nothing, returning 'Success' (it seemed silly but I saw that somewhere on stackoverflow). How can I reach it?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was advised by @diego-borba to send 'SUCCESS' from servlet back to the .jsp page.

```
 response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.getWriter().write("SUCCESS"); // Sending a success response
```

It didn't work for me (the response was treated like an error, and SUCCESS was treated like an error message), but I tried sending json object that would say { success : true }, and it worked (because ajax has dataType:'json' specified). Have no idea why 200 status code is treated as an error tho but it all worked this way:

```
 JsonObject myObj = new JsonObject();
 myObj.addProperty("success", true);
 response.getWriter().println(myObj.toString());
```

And here's the ajax code :

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url:"/adminUser?save=save",
        dataType:'json',
        data: {save: 'save', login:login, pass1:pass1, userName:userName, email:email,
        bukhUsersId: bukhUsersId, otdelId: otdelId, roleId: roleId, checkActive: checkActive},
        success: function (xhr, status, error) {
                 top.location.href = "/adminUser?action=spisok";
        },
        error : function(xhr, status, error) {
                  $("#errorLogin").text(xhr.responseText);
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```java
String login = request.getParameter("login");
if (adminSecurityDAOImpl.isUserExist(login)) {
    response.sendError(400, "Пользователь с таким логином уже существует");
    response.flushBuffer();
    return;
} else {
    adminSecurityDAOImpl.saveUser(user);

    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.getWriter().write("SUCCESS"); // Sending a success response
    response.flushBuffer();
    return;
}
```

Now, in your jQuery AJAX call, you can modify the success function to handle the response:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/adminUser?save=save",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { save: 'save', login: login, pass1: pass1, userName: userName, email: email, bukhUsersId: bukhUsersId, otdelId: otdelId, roleId: roleId, checkActive: checkActive },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data === "SUCCESS") {
            top.location.href = "/adminUser?action=spisok";
        } else {
            // Handle other unexpected success responses, if any
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        $("#errorLogin").text("Пользователь с таким логином уже существует");
    }
});
```

In the context of the jQuery AJAX `success` callback function, the `data` variable represents the response data returned by the server. When the AJAX call is successful and the server sends a response, the `data` parameter in the `success` function holds the content of that response. [Check this out](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

With this setup, when the servlet sends `"SUCCESS"` as the response, the success function of your AJAX call will be triggered, and the page will be redirected to `"/adminUser?action=spisok"`. If the servlet sends anything other than `"SUCCESS"`, you can handle it within the `success` function accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. It's still going to that 'ERROR' clause and doesn't redirect as I want it to. It thinks that ' SUCCESS' is an error message.

Comment: I added the `ContentType` configuration in my answer, maybe this was the problem.

Comment: no, still just prints 'SUCCESS' in the div for the error :)
I can probably manage it by checking what exactly is sent to the error. But it doesn't make sense. There should be some way to reach success clause if it exists)